# lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid predicate

Tags: python-3.6, lxml

I get the following `lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid predicate` error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "check_1337.py", line 18, in
>
> ```
> //div[@class = "_3iyw"]//div[@class = "_6beq _7cdk _6beo"]//div[@class = "_7om2 _3gim _ 7cdk"]//div [@class = "5s61"]//div[@class = "_7cdi"]')
> ```
>
> File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 1583, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
>
> File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 305, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.**call**
>
> File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
>
> lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid predicate

from the following code:

```
from lxml.etree import HTML
import requests

url = "https://m.facebook.com/?_rdr"
response = requests.get(url)
root = HTML(response.content)

tempII = root.find("body").xpath('//div[@id = "viewport"]//div[@id = "page"]//div[@id = "rootcontainer]//div[@class = "async_compose _2v9s"]//div[@id = "MRoot"]\
//div[@class = "_3iyw"]//div[@class = "_6beq _7cdk _6beo"]//div[@class = "_7om2 _3gim _ 7cdk"]//div [@class = "5s61"]//div[@class = "_7cdi"]')

print (tempII)
```

Can you help me find out the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at *rootcontainer* in your *find* call.
**Before** this word you put a double quote (this is OK),
but failed to put another double quote **after** it.

**Another detail:** A bit later you have: *@class = "_7om2 _3gim _ 7cdk"*.

Are you sure that there should be **four** classes here (*_7om2*, *_3gim*,
*_* and *7cdk*)?

Using "_" as a class name is a weird practice.
Maybe instead of 2 last classes there should be **one** class *_7cdk*?
Note that a bit earlier you have just *_7cdk*.

This flaw is not likely to cause any exception, but the result of *find*
probably will be empty.
Be cautious as you write such predicates, as errors like this are quite
difficult to identify.

Comment: no the class is like that |@class = "_7om2 _3gim _ 7cdk"| it's one class.            thanks the problem was with the missing double quote after |root container|.

Comment: why the result is empty?

Comment: See *Another detail* in my answer. Instead of *_ 7cdk* (two classes) probably there should be *_7cdk* (one class). You should also take a look at the response received, whether it actually contains elements mentioned in the predicate.